# paypal cannot delete sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Paypal developer site is not letting me delete sandbox account. the error message it shows is "something went wrong one or more sandbox accounts could not be deleted. try again".

Any idea what should be done to delete the test account (this is a 3rd account in addition to buyer & facilitator account...so not grayed out)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be reported to Paypal and has nothing to do with computer programming *per se*.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug - it's being looked at the PayPal end.